# Remove Elements by Type from Lists in a Nested List

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm writing a function that takes a list of lists and is supposed to calculate the mean of each column in the list, but the first three spaces of the list are strings while the next six are the integers I'm averaging. I don't know how to remove all strings from the list of lists so that I can average just the integers. Here's my code so far:

```
def display_averages(input_list):
    print (input_list) #This is here to see that the input list is correctly nested. Will be removed once the code works
    for i in input_list: #This should be the bit that removes all strings, but doesn't
        if type(i) is str:
                    input_list.remove(i)
    temp = (sum(i) for i in zip(*input_list))
    fin = []
    for l in temp:
        fin.append(l / len(input_list))
    print("MDL: Mean-",fin[0])
    print("SPT: Mean-",fin[1])
    print("HRP: Mean-",fin[2])
    print("SDC: Mean-",fin[3])
    print("LTK: Mean-",fin[4])
    print("2MR: Mean-",fin[5])
```

Input would be along the lines of:

```
temp_data = [['FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME', 'CATEGORY', 0, 20, 50, 0, 30, 90]]
temp_data.append(['FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME', 'CATEGORY', 100, 80, 100, 50, 90, 100])
display_averages(temp_data)
```

Desired output would be:

```
MDL: Mean- 50.0
SPT: Mean- 50.0
HRP: Mean- 75.0
SDC: Mean- 25.0
LTK: Mean- 60.0
2MR: Mean- 95.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy` package to handle the 2d array (list of lists) which also provides you nice functions like `mean`.

**Try this:**

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(temp_data)
info = { "MDL": 3, "SPT": 4, "HRP": 5, "SDC": 6, "LTK": 7, "2MR": 8 } # Temp dict stores respective key-column

for k, v in info.items():
    info[k] = arr[:, v].astype(float).mean()
    print(f"{k}: Mean-", info[k])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
MDL: Mean- 50.0
SPT: Mean- 50.0
HRP: Mean- 75.0
SDC: Mean- 25.0
LTK: Mean- 60.0
2MR: Mean- 95.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the first three elements are strings and the rest six are numbers,
the following will give you the list of the averages:

```
print([sum(l[3:]) / 6 for l in temp_data])
```